# Conducting a thorough investigation into a casual issue

Tags: phrase-usage

> I conducted a thorough investigation into artificial intelligence.

I think  "conducted a thorough investigation" may be too strong for the above sentence. I think it should be used for example when a crime is happened and an organization like the police conducts a thorough investigation into it.

Is it natural to use this phrase in the context of a casual issue which is performed by a single casual person, like the above sentence?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that "investigation" may not be the correct word for this case. If the intended meaning is that the speaker was looking for some wrong doing, or malice, then to investigate would be reasonable.

However, if the goal is just to acquire knowledge on the subject, I would use words like "thorough research into..." or "in depth analysis of ...", more casually : "to look into ..."

Comment: What about "conducted"? Is it a good word in this context

Comment: Yeah that's fine IMO